# Implement function defined as entry point

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a `python` program which simply removes green background from images.

Now I want to implement my function `remove_green_background()` defined as an entry point. I have searched through many websites and also through stackoverflow but can't understand how entry points works.

So anybody can explain it to me using this code in detail that where to put those entry points?

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os


def rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b):
    maxc = max(r, g, b)
    minc = min(r, g, b)
    v = maxc
    if minc == maxc:
        return 0.0, 0.0, v
    s = (maxc-minc) / maxc
    rc = (maxc-r) / (maxc-minc)
    gc = (maxc-g) / (maxc-minc)
    bc = (maxc-b) / (maxc-minc)
    if r == maxc:
        h = bc-gc
    elif g == maxc:
        h = 2.0+rc-bc
    else:
        h = 4.0+gc-rc
    h = (h/6.0) % 1.0
    return h, s, v


GREEN_RANGE_MIN_HSV = (100, 80, 70)
GREEN_RANGE_MAX_HSV = (185, 255, 255)

def remove_green_background():
    # Load image and convert it to RGBA, so it contains alpha channel
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(Filepath)
    im = Image.open(Filepath)
    im = im.convert('RGBA')

    # Go through all pixels and turn each 'green' pixel to transparent
    pix = im.load()
    width, height = im.size
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r, g, b, a = pix[x, y]
            h_ratio, s_ratio, v_ratio = rgb_to_hsv(r / 255.0, g / 255.0, b / 255.0)
            h, s, v = (h_ratio * 360, s_ratio * 255, v_ratio * 255)

            min_h, min_s, min_v = GREEN_RANGE_MIN_HSV
            max_h, max_s, max_v = GREEN_RANGE_MAX_HSV
            if min_h <= h <= max_h and min_s <= s <= max_s and min_v <= v <= max_v:
                pix[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 0)


    im.save(name + '.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_green_background()
```

Comment: @Obaid_Ur_Rehman what did you want to do here: `if __name__ == '__ remove_green_background __':`

Comment: Sorry, That was a mistake while copying code. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, entry point is defined as the function name. So simply change your function name to remove_green_background() and this would be your entry point.

Answer (score 2):

The other way round:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_green_background()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_green_background()
```